# How to correct the selected feature options when the browser is refreshed?

Tags: javascript

When the page refreshes, I want the options I selected in the two selection menus to be the default, but when I select an item and refresh the page, the last options I selected show up. How can I make an option default each time I refresh the page, even if another option is selected when refreshing the page? codepen demo: https://codepen.io/BerkayAkgurgen/pen/LYbrBEa

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.getElementById('usd').selected = "true"
        document.getElementById('try').selected = "true"
    })
```

Comment: Consider using `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`?

Comment: This way is so far for this page. İs there any different way?

Comment: _"This way is so far for this page"_ sorry may you explain? I don't understand

Comment: I mean "this way is so long for this page"

Comment: ...but if it's the solution to the problem?

Comment: Since a problem in javascript often has many solutions, I looked for alternative ways.

Comment: there are not many solution to keeping data between page reloads.